# Kannst du diesen sehr rätselhaften Nebensatz erklären?

Tags: usage, gender, modal-verb

Folgendes ist aus Geschichte vom alten Kind von Jenny Erpenbeck. Es geht im Buch um ein Mädchen ohne Namen, ein Waisenkind, das im Kinderheim lebt, und es wurde uns schon erklärt, wie in der Schule das Mädchen immer tut, als ob es dumm wäre (obwohl es in Wirklichkeit nicht dumm ist - deshalb die Bezeichnung  unten "scheinbar wirkliche Dummheit"), um sich im untertesten Platz in der Schulhierarchie sicher zu fühlen.

> Und indem scheinbar wirkliche Dummheit, Dummheit, die beinahe größer
> ist, **als es selbst die Dummheit derjenigen sein dürfte**, die immerhin
> die unterste Position in der Hierarchie einnimmt, der Grund dafür ist,
> dass das Mädchen von Lehrern wie von Schülern aufgegeben wird – denn
> offensichtlich ist es weder faul, noch weigert es sich aus
> bösem Willen, noch glaubt es, es sei etwas Besseres, nein, nur dumm
> ist es —, insofern endet selbst im Zustand des Aufgegebenseins nicht
> seine Zugehörigkeit zu den anderen, die im Gegensatz zu ihm ihren
> Geist unter großer Anstrengung vorantreiben.

Den Nebensatz in Fettschrift kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Meine Fragen:

1. Worauf bezieht sich das "es"? Bezieht "es" sich möglicherweise auf "Dummheit", obwohl "Dummheit" weiblich ist und nach meinem Verständnis "sie" statt "es" fordern würde?
2. Wird "als" benutzt, um einen Vergleich auszudrücken? Das würde mich verwirren, weil die Person mit der scheinbaren Dummheit dieselbe ist, wie die Person, die die unterste Position in der Hierarchie einnimmt. Führt also stattdessen "als" einen Grund ein, so wie man erwarten würde, wenn zum Beispiel "umso größer" statt "beinahe größer" steht?
3. Was bedeutet in diesem Fall "sein dürfte"?

Danke!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ein äußerst komplizierter Satz, der Form nach und auch inhaltlich! Aber der Teil, um den es geht, den kann man herausziehen, denn er ist ein Einschub (eine Apposition, die die gerade genannte Dummheit näher bestimmt (der Einschub ist anders als der zweite später nicht durch Gedankenstriche gekennzeichnet, das wäre aber besser):

> Dummheit, die beinahe größer ist, als es selbst die Dummheit
> derjenigen sein dürfte, die immerhin die unterste Position in der
> Hierarchie einnimmt,

1

Zunächst vereinfacht (es soll mal nicht stören, dass sich die Bedeutung so zunächst verändert):

> Diese Dummheit ist größer als die Dummheit von derjenigen [PERSON],
> die ganz unten ist.

Wie Janka schon sagte, in dieser Variante verschwindet das "es", es erscheint also in deinem Satz, weil nicht mit einer anderen Dummheit verglichen wird, sondern mit einem ganzen Vergleichssatz. Dessen Kernaussage ist:

- (D2:) Die Dummheit der Person ganz unten ist SO groß,
- und (D1:) eine andere Dummheit ist größer.

Das ist der Vergleich, der hier in Wirklichkeit mit "D-1 ist größer als [D-2 es ist]" benannt wird. Dieses "es" trit ein, weil der eingeklammerte Satz vereinfacht enthalten würde, dass "D-2 so groß ist" -- das Adjektiv "groß" fehlt in diesem Satz. Im Deutschen tritt "es" nun als ein Pronomen auf, das sich auf Eigenschaften bezieht, etwa in einem anderen Beispiel:

- "Ihre Dummheit ist groß, ihr Ehrgeiz ist es auch."
- "ist *es* auch" = "ist auch *groß*"

Ich glaube, dass in dem Vergleichssatz dasselbe vorliegt, obwohl es keinen Weg gäbe, das Adjektiv "groß" hier als solches einzusetzen. Der Bezug darauf ist aber da, weil auch das Kopulaverb "ist" anwesend ist. "Größer als es D2 ist" = "Größer als D2 groß-ist" bzw. "Größer als die Größe von D2".

2

Soviel zum "es", für das ich alles als reale Aussagen formuliert habe. Zusätzlich steht hier "dürfte". Dieses Modalverb bezieht sich darauf, dass etwas in irgend einem Sinn "möglich" ist. "Größer als D2 sein dürfte" = D2 kann/könnte maximal eine gewisse Größe haben, aber egal wie – D1 ist in jedem Fall noch größer.

In Jankas Meinung wird "dürfte" subjektiv gedeutet (also epistemisch?). Ich denke, es ist offen, es gibt verschiedene mögliche Schattierungen, die gemeint sein könnten. In jedem Fall bedeutet "dürfte" etwas Ähnliches wie "könnte", es betont aber mehr, dass etwas möglich ist, weil es eine Quelle dafür gibt, die diese Möglichkeit bestimmt: jemand erlaubt es / das Gesetz erlaubt es / die Umstände sind so, dass sie etwas möglich werden lassen. Ich glaub hier ist es letzteres: Wenn jemand in der Schulhierarchie ganz unten ist, dann entspricht dem ein typischer Grad von Dummheit; es geht also um die Grade an Dummheit, die eine solche Position sozusagen hergeben würde. Die Aussage ist also: "Wie groß auch immer die Dummheit sein könnte, die sich aus ihrer Position ergeben mag ..."

3

Kann ich noch was subjektives dazu sagen... ich find die Passage ist schlechter Stil. Es ist komplex aber nicht kunstvoll, sondern verworren und nahezu unverständlich, weil unklar ist, was sich worauf bezieht. Noch dazu wird eine lange Satzperiode anfangs mit "indem" eingeleitet, dann kommen Nebengedanken, dann überlegt der Autor es sich anders, und greift die Sache mit "insofern" wieder auf, was aber nicht dasselbe bedeutet.

Comment: Ok, danke Alazon - ist es auch möglich auf Deutsch zu sagen, "Ich bin dümmer als sie ist?"

Comment: Für mich, ja, aber ein "es" dazu würde auch nicht schaden...

Answer (score 1):

In deinem Beispiel gibt es ein Komma zuviel, denn der Vergleich gehört mit zu dem kleinen Relativsatz davor.

> … Dummheit, die größer ist als es selbst die Dummheit derjenigen sein dürfte, die …

---

Lass mich ein einfacheres Beispiel verwenden:

> Idiotie ist Dummheit, die größer ist als normale Dummheit.

Hier benötigt man kein solches *es*, denn der Vergleichsgegenstand ist das Wort *Idiotie* aus dem Hauptsatz. Lass mich jedoch ein Verb einfügen:

> Idiotie ist Dummheit, die größer ist als es normale Dummheit ist.

Nun ist der Vergleichsgegenstand der ganze Teilsatz *Idiotie ist Dummheit, die größer ist* und der Vergleich muss nun ebenfalls ein gültiger Teilsatz sein. Deshalb braucht man das *es*:

> Es ist normale Dummheit.

Worauf bezieht sich also dieses *es*? Auf alles, was durch *Idiotie* nicht korrekt beschrieben wird.

---

Dieses *sein dürfen* ist ein abgeschwächtes *sein*. Die Verfasserin behauptet nicht, es sei ein Fakt, sie vermutet es nur. Das ist ein sogenannter subjektiver Gebrauch eines Modalverbs.